# Php Validate Form Data Some Required Some Optional

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have a php data collection form where some of the fields are required and some are optional. Basically the page has 5 inputs and there are 10 instances of the 5 fields. This makes it easy for a person to enter 10 events at once. 4 of the fields are required while 1 field is optional. Some of the required fields need to accept 0 as a valid entry. I'm getting a little lost at how I should go about validating that this information was entered correctly.

Basically the end result is 5 different arrays of 10 values. The user doesn't need to enter 10 events, 10 events are displayed by default in case they are needed. So I'm looking to get rid of the empty values and check that all the required values were filled in.

I also need to make sure I don't just do an array_filter, because this could rearrange the order that the person entered the data. If the user only entered the 1st value on the first line and entered all the data but the 1st line on the 2nd line, this would result in 1 valid entry and not 2 non valid entries.

Answer (score 0):

Took awhile but I have written a function that will handle this. The function takes an 2d array of required data, and a 2d array of optional data. It returns the final array if successful, returns 1 if all required information is blank, returns 2 if not all required information matches (some fields are entered for some and others aren't entered for others).

```
//make sure all arrays have the same amount of values
function validate_arrays($req,$op) {
$req_key = array_keys($req);
$op_key = array_keys($op);

$final = array();
$check = array();
$empty = true;
$all_equal = true;

for($a = 0; $a < count($req); $a++) {
    unset($data);
    $data = array();
    for($b = 0; $b < count($req[$req_key[$a]]); $b++) {
        //check data
        $test = trim($req[$req_key[$a]][$b]);
        if(strcmp(trim($req[$req_key[$a]][$b]),"") == 0) {
            //required is blank
            array_push($data,false);
        }
        else {
            $empty = false;
            array_push($data,true);
        }
    }
    array_push($check,$data);
}

//check if all data arrays were the same
for($a = 0; $a < (count($check)-1); $a++) {
    if($check[$a] !== $check[$a+1]) {
        $all_equal = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$empty) {
    if($all_equal) {
        //changes the arrays to match the required entries, will get rid of empty values, will keep op fields with the correct req fields
        for($a = 0; $a < count($req); $a++) {
            $final[$req_key[$a]] = array();
            for($b = 0; $b < count($req[$req_key[$a]]); $b++) {
                if($check[$a][$b] == true) {
                    //add data to the array
                    array_push($final[$req_key[$a]],$req[$req_key[$a]][$b]);
                }
            }
        }
        for($a = 0; $a < count($op); $a++) {
            $final[$op_key[$a]] = array();
            for($b = 0; $b < count($op[$op_key[$a]]); $b++) {
                if($check[$a][$b] == true) {
                    //add data to the array
                    array_push($final[$op_key[$a]],$op[$op_key[$a]][$b]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //all required fields did not have the same amount of data
        $final = 2;
    }
}
else {
    //all required fields were empty
    $final = 1;
}
return $final;
}
```